# Handling cue in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to remove this from my css:

```
::cue  {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS",Helvetica,sans-serif;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black,0 1px black,1px 0 black,0 -1px #000;
}
```

And put it in my javascript. How do I do that?

Comment: @LOTUSMS How would you solve this with jQuery as opposed to vanilla JS?

Comment: .css() passes css. Am I understanding this wrong?

Comment: I don't think it is possible with javascript or jquery

Comment: @LOTUSMS You are. You can modify CSS with vanilla JS (jQuery is written in vanilla). The problem is targeting this selector. As Adam said, I don't believe it's possible to target it.

Comment: @MikeC Ah, gotcha.. I didn't notice the selector. I thought he just wanted to apply CSS to an element with JS (jQuery). Fair enough

Comment: If Jquery can do it, JS can too... the question is how ? It's really annoying to create a JS framework and depend on css only for this code...

Comment: maybe an include script or else should do it ?

Comment: `$("head").append("<style> ::cue{ ... } </style>")`

Comment: Nice idea @dandavis. alexino hope this works for you !

Comment: @dandavis : it's not pretty, but it's work ! Thanks you. By the way, does "document.head" need to be use on DOMContentLoaded or else ?

Comment: @alexino2: the head is always available if the script is running.

Comment: document.head is pretty cool after all, he also change the css whenever you use innerHTML on the createElement("style"), and seems to work with all browser :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is an example you can use.

html page

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css" defer/>
        <script src="JS/script.js"></script>
    </head> 
<body> 
   <h1 id="cue">Hello World</h1>
   <button id="btnText">Change Text</button>    

</body
</html>

javascript file

window.onload = function () {

    "use strict";

    var myText = document.getElementById("cue"),
        btnChange = document.getElementById("btnText");

    btnChange.addEventListener("click", function () {

        myText.style.color = "white";
        myText.style.fontFamily = "Trebuchet MS, Helvetica,sans-serif";
        myText.style.textShadow = "-1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px #000";    
    })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dandavis, here is a solution that works:

```js
var s = document.createElement("style");
    s.type = "text/css";
    s.innerHTML = "::cue  {"
        + "background:none;"
        + "color: #fff;"
        + "font-family: 'Trebuchet MS',Helvetica,sans-serif;"
        + "text-shadow: -1px 0 black,0 1px black,1px 0 black,0 -1px #000;"
        + "}";

document.head.appendChild(s);
```